# CreatedAt in MongoDB can´t be sorted

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

This is a Sort example :
const points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return b - a});

Array products

```
 let a = [{
    "_id": "61ce7052b2c78ab4ae89c731",
    "title": "Alcohol",
    "description": "Para medicina",
    "categories": [
        "Art"
    ],
    "price": 300,
    "rating": 1,
    "image": "https://veterinariaeljockey.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/alcohol-etilico-purocol-500cc.jpg",
    "quantity": 3,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-31T02:52:02.833Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-12-31T02:52:02.833Z",
    "__v": 0
},
 {
    "_id": "61ce6fefb2c78ab4ae89c72e",
    "title": "Liquido de Frenos",
    "description": "Elemento para el auto",
    "categories": [
        "Services"
    ],
    "price": 2500,
    "rating": 1,
    "image": "http://proyesa.com.sv/site/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/liquido-para-frenos-bosch.jpg",
    "quantity": 23,
    "createdAt": "2021-12-31T02:50:23.974Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-12-31T02:50:23.974Z",
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

Sort

```
    useEffect(() => {
    if (time === "newest") {
      if (!filterProducts || filterProducts.length == 0) {
        setFilterProducts(...products);
      } else {
        setFilterProducts((prev) =>
          [...prev].sort((a, b) => a.createdAt - b.createdAt)
        );
      }
    } else {
      setFilterProducts((prev) => [...prev].sort((a, b) => b.createdAt - a.createdAt));
    }
  }, [time]);
```

When I touch "Newest" products sort by default. But I touch "Oldest" nothing happens

Thanks for helping!

Comment: `createdAt` is a `string`. You need to convert it into a date, then the sorting would work as you expect

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createdAt is a string, in order to sort the list by date you must convert it into Date.

example:

```
 setFilterProducts((prev) =>
    [...prev].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.createdAt) - new Date(b.createdAt));
```